# pvcm function of plm package: insufficient number of observations

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I was doing panel data regression on this data set

```
Panel <- foreign::read.dta("http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta")
```

I tried this code

```
library(plm)
grun.tvarw <- pvcm(y ~ x1+x2+x3+opinion, data=Panel, index=c("country", "year"), 
                                         model="within",effect="time")
```

and hit this error

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : insufficient number of observations

Answer (score 0):

There are too few observations for the model to be estimable. As you run the "within" model with "time" effects of pvcm, this means as least one time period has too few individuals (countries in your case). To work around this: reduce your model (less covariates) or gather more data.

I noticed, the development version of package `plm` has a little re-fined error message for function `pvcm`, making it very clear now:

> "insufficient number of observations for at least one group in time
> dimension, so defined model is non-estimable"

However, also note that the development version has a "relaxed" requirement for the "within" case, to allow estimation of coefficients while the variance may not be estimable. This seems to be your case. With the development version:

```
grun.tvarw

Model Formula: y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + opinion
<environment: 0x000002029e1a41b0>

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)           x1          x2          x3 opinionAgree opinionDisag opinionStr disag
1990    600623799   7149909953  2254722934  4435660067  -9267273786  -3257090663      -9041210110
1991  -4880291582   2213155197  1728079945  4159874815  -2533552203   1861471566       7530349188
1992   7036268598 -11823277339 -4378563176  1866185979   3473524936  -7517991777               NA
1993   7547077983  -2869387348 -1731037077 -4312514240   -591804221  -6134972630       1644534407
1994   3805759711   4194246580 -1189281236  -910348660           NA  -1305214400      -6052461645
1995 -34186043205  51897462198 30758223157 32685996482 -10406734021           NA     -68965666622
1996 -36629556562  28268793685 11441352022  7011818475  12757721849  26540735507       8989481882
1997   2320680543   2253171325  1257612044   856909300           NA  -3858719596       -235131468
1998   9890692415  -6141048367  1393643157  1727332774  -8429002530  -7492579634               NA
1999  -1293654096  -1142066476  -373727888  -333155816           NA   7804815894       1954301533
```

For the standard errors being non-estimable, see:

```
grun.tvarw$std.error
     (Intercept)          x1         x2         x3 opinionAgree opinionDisag opinionStr disag
1990         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN          NaN              NaN
1991         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN          NaN              NaN
1992 14126958277 25525131798 8485730761 4516598262   8548421551  14146617710               NA
1993         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN          NaN              NaN
1994 15086875566 16004947427 2135203307 2320195481           NA   8997696773       4108384256
1995  9271035694 13396558052 7252615725 7549016727   3466235726           NA      16351976836
1996         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN          NaN              NaN
1997   954219632  1272378739  479840558  387024268           NA   1267662702       1114132188
1998  9474949930  8294986437 2084710449 2016772895   5287606864   8526057048               NA
1999  2287039302  2113550897  944000564  416753440           NA   3137852641       2148811284
```

Comment: "development version" <- how to get this? Just reinstall the package again

Comment: `# install.packages("remotes")` # remove '#' if pkg 'remotes' is not installed
`remotes::install_github("ycroissant/plm")`